# cypress - use request for login

Tags: cypress

I am trying to test a demo app with cypress. If I use UI to login, it works.

But, looking at https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/testing-your-app#Logging-in, the following code does not work.

```
describe('The Login By Request', () => {
    it('successfully logs in with request', () => {

       cy.request('POST', '/', {
        username: "johnny@email.com",
        passwd: "12345678"
      })       

      cy.visit('/')
      // UI should reflect this user being logged in
      cy.get('h1').should('contain', 'Svelte To-Do List')

    })
  })
```

The result is it could not find the h1 element and the browser is left on the login page.

baseUrl is set to localhost:5000

What am I doing wrong?

Updated:

new code

```
describe('The Login By Request', () => {
    it('successfully logs in with request', () => {

      cy.request('POST', '/', {
        username: "johnny@email.com",
        passwd: "12345678"
      }).its('body').then((body) => {
        cy.visit(`/`)
        cy.log(body)
        cy.get('h1').should('contain', 'Svelte To-Do List')         
      });

  })
})
```

From the command log console

Console was cleared. cypress_runner.js:201262:32

Command:  request cypress_runner.js:201254:13

Request:

Object { "Request Body": "{"username":"johnny@email.com","passwd":"12345678"}", "Request Headers": {…}, "Request URL": "http://localhost:5000/", "Response Body": "\r\n<html lang="en">\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\tSvelte To-Do List\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n", "Response Headers": {…}, "Response Status": 200 }

cypress_runner.js:201254:13

Yielded:

Object { status: 200, duration: 75, body: "\r\n<html lang="en">\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\tSvelte To-Do List\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n", headers: {…} }

cypress_runner.js:201254:13

Console was cleared. cypress_runner.js:201262:32

Command:   its cypress_runner.js:201254:13

Property:  .body cypress_runner.js:201254:13

Subject:

Object { body: "\r\n<html lang="en">\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\tSvelte To-Do List\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n", headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", isOkStatusCode: true, requestHeaders: {…}, requestBody: "{"username":"johnny@email.com","passwd":"12345678"}", duration: 6, allRequestResponses: (1) […] }

cypress_runner.js:201254:13

Yielded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1'>
    <title>Svelte To-Do List</title>
    <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='/favicon.png'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/global.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/bundle.css'>
    <script defer src='/build/bundle.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

So though the request returns 200, I don't think that I have actually logged in - there is no token returned. Whereas manually using the browser does give a token. And using cypress to log in via the UI also gives a token. And using cypress to directly call the login api returns a token.

It just seems to the cypress request via html that does not work.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73049398/writing-to-svelte-writable-store-value-from-cypress/73156372#73156372 This is the code that I found worked.

Answer (score 1):

It could happen because at the time the `visit` command is called, the browser session is not created yet. For testing purpose, you can chain your `visit` command on your request.
However, for an easy transition between pages, I suggest you simply save your token in the browser session before the `visit` is fired up:

```
cy.request('POST', '/auth', {
    username,
    password,
}).its('body.token').then(token => {
  cy.visit(`/`, {
    onBeforeLoad(win) {
      win.sessionStorage.setItem('token', token);
    },
  });
});
```

P.S. better used in a custom command or a helper function inside a `before` hook.

Also, you can use `visit` command with auth property, if your test requires a one-login scenario:

```
cy.visit('/', {
  auth: {
    username,
    password,
  },
})
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for getting back.
I am obviously not getting something here. Just to add context, I have a cypress test that checks the api calls from the svelte front end to the node backend and that works. the token is received and stored and used in subsequent calls. And if I use the browser manually, I can see the token in the console log (from logging in svelte)
But after its code you suggested, I cy.log(body) and that shows an empty body. Hence the h1 assertion fails.
So manually I get body contents after logging in (and using the UI in cypress). But request gives an empty body.

Comment: Hi John. Does your `cy.request(...)` returns something? Could you run the auth request and track on cypress logs, what does it return? I'm mostly curious about the body format

Comment: Hi Alex, I have updated the original question with output from the command log console.